# Condition to separability of a Banach space.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, examples-counterexamples

I am trying to prove the following statement:

> Let X be a Banach space and $X^{*}$ its topological dual space. If there exists a countable family of functions $(f_{n})_{n} \subset X^{*}$ such that for every $x,y \in X$, $x \neq y$, there exists $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f_{m}(x) \neq f_{m}(y)$ then X is separable.

I don't even know if this is true. I've been looking for counterexamples but the only non-separable Banach space familiar to me is $l_{\infty}$ and I can't find such a family of functions there. Thank you.

Comment: I don't actually know how to solve this one (or even if it's true), but the way I would start would be to look at the preimages of the rationals under the functions $f_m$. Remember that elements of the dual space are always continuous.

Comment: With $f_m(x) = x_m$, you have a countable family in $(l_\infty)^\ast$ such that for all $x\neq y$ there is an $m$ with $f_m(x)\neq f_m(y)$.

Comment: Daniel, you should probably post this as an answer. Actually, there is nothing special about $\ell_\infty$ here. You can take any $X^{**}$ for $X$ separable as a counter-example (this is due to Goldstine's theorem, of course).

Answer (score 2):

Concrete example by [Daniel Fischer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/727829/condition-to-separability-of-a-banach-space#comment1519776_727829):

> With $f_m(x) = x_m$, you have a countable family in $(l_\infty)^\ast$ such that for all $x\neq y$ there is an $m$ with $f_m(x)\neq f_m(y)$.

Generalization by [Tomek Kania](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/727829/condition-to-separability-of-a-banach-space#comment1535097_727829):

> Actually, there is nothing special about $\ell_\infty$ here. You can take any $X^{**}$ for $X$ separable as a counter-example (this is due to [Goldstine's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldstine_theorem), of course).